# Enlighten Designs Tutorial - HTML5 Markup

Tags: html5

I have taken the following design from a tutorial done in 2006, and have decided to markup it up in HTML5. The design is as follows:

[image: enlighten desings]

My markup is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Enlighten Designs - About</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body id="about">
    <div id="page-wrapper">
        <nav id="site-nav" role="navigation">
            <h2 class="visually-hidden">Site Navigation</h2>
            <ul>
                <li id="about-nav"><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li id="services-nav"><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                <li id="portfolio-nav"><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li id="contact-nav"><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <header id="page-header" role="banner">
            <h1>Enlighten Designs</h1>
        </header>
        <main id="content" class="container" role="main">
            <div id="primary">
                <section>
                    <h2>About</h2>
                    <p><strong>Enlighten Designs</strong> is an internet solutions provider that specialises in front and back end development. To view some of the websites we have created view our <a href="#">portfolio</a>.</p>
                    <p>We are currently undergoing a &quot;face lift&quot;, so if you have any questions or would like more information about the sevices we provide please feel free to contact us.</p>
                </section>
                <section>
                    <h2>Contact Us</h2>
                    <address>
                        Phone: <span>(07) 853 6060</span><br>
                        Fax: <span>(07) 853 6060</span><br>
                        Email: <a href="mailto:info@enlighten.co.nz"><span>info@enlighten.co.nz</span></a><br>
                        P.O. Box: <span>14159, Hamilton, New Zealand</span>
                    </address>
                    <p><a href="#">More contact information</a>...</p>
                </section>
            </div><!-- end primary -->  
            <aside id="secondary" role="complementary">
                <h2>Featured Projects</h2>
                <h3>The New Zealand National Party</h3>
                <p>We recently launched the <a href="#" rel="external">New Zealand National Party</a> website - Lorem ipsem dolor sit amet. Pita ala pesama borak na falanuisen</p>
                <h3>Greensets</h3>
                <p>We recently launched the <a href="#" rel="external">Greensets</a> website - Lorem ipsem dolor sit amet. Pita ala pesama borak na falanuisen</p>
                <h3>Nutrition Care</h3>
                <p>We recently launched the <a href="#" rel="external">Nutrition Care</a> website - Lorem ipsem dolor sit amet. Pita ala pesama borak na falanuisen</p>
            </aside>
        </main>
        <footer id="page-footer" role="contentinfo">
            <div class="fl">
                <p>Copyright &copy; Enlighten Designs</p>
                <p>Powered by Enlighten Hosting and Vadmin 3.0 CMS</p>
            </div>
            <ul class="fr">
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Terms of Trade</a></li>
            </ul>
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I ran it through [this validator](https://html5.validator.nu/) and got the following results. "The document is valid HTML5 + ARIA + SVG 1.1 + MathML 2.0" I'd say that's a nice start. =)

Comment: Are you using [those ids for css hooks](http://screwlewse.com/2010/07/dont-use-id-selectors-in-css/)?

Answer (score 1):

If possible with your CSS, I’d put the `header` (with the site title) before the `nav`. It would produce a nicer document outline.

Your use of `strong` doesn’t seem to be appropriate. It must only be used for "strong importance, seriousness, or urgency". Use [`span`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/text-level-semantics.html#the-span-element) (+ CSS) or maybe [`b`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/text-level-semantics.html#the-b-element) instead.

If the sidebar with "featured projects" exists on every page of the site, you should not include it in the [`main` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/grouping-content.html#the-main-element). But if it’s only on the homepage, it’s fine.

You could use URIs for the telephone and the fax number, too: [`tel` URI scheme](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3966) (see example below, but note that I did not verify that it’s the best/correct URI syntax for this kind of number).

Your use of `br` (in `address`) is [not appropriate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27327110/1591669), because the line breaks don’t seem to be part of the content here. Instead, you should use a so-called "block level" element for each "line" so that even text-browser users can easily understand this content.
In your case, the [`dl` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/grouping-content.html#the-dl-element) seems to be appropriate (while it was defined as *definition list* in HTML 4.01, its meaning in HTML5 was changed to *description list*):

```
<address>
  <dl>
    <dt>Phone:</dt> <dd><a href="tel:078536060">(07) 853 6060</a></dd>
    <dt>Fax:</dt> <dd><a href="tel:078536060">(07) 853 6060</a></dd>
    <dt>Email:</dt> <dd><a href="mailto:info@enlighten.co.nz">info@enlighten.co.nz</a></dd>
    <dt>P.O. Box:</dt> <dd>14159, Hamilton, New Zealand</dd>
  </dl>
</address>
```

You could use the [`small` element for the copyright notice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21489636/1591669).